# Excel Distinct Count Values in columns using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

SO i have this data **Table**, about 5000 rows.. **ID** column is a unique identifier, **Med** is a category column (Med A and Med B), **Date** column, **Month** (I extracted the month number from the date column)

The issue
I need to do a distinct count of all unique **ID** that has **Med** = Med A for all **Month** 7

I have written this, but i do not think its giving me an incorrect result, as i manually filtered the data and could confirm its indeed incorrect

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[ID], (Table1[Med] = "Med A") * (Table1[Month] = 7))))`

could anybody help?

Comment: The formula looks correct to me. In what way do you think the results are wrong?

Comment: If you provide your data within the question - using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) - plus your expected result - it is easier to help you.

Comment: What about countifs() ?

Comment: What result do you get? Do you have any space or hidden character?

Comment: Please edit your question to post your data as text which can be copy/pasted. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Well, you are filtering the month but not the year; unless you are looking for any july of any year you won't get what you want. Use something like `=MONTH(C2)&YEAR(C2)`. You can also just use a `=COUNTIFS(Table1[Med],"Med A",Table1[Month&Year],"72023")`.